# Получить данные через htmlrequest

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет!
Я пытаюсь получить данные по htmlrequest с другой страницы сайта, у меня есть функция:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://site.com/page2', false);
xhr.send();
if (xhr.status != 200) {
  alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText ); // пример вывода: 404: Not Found
} else {
  alert( xhr.responseText ); // responseText -- текст ответа.
}
```

Эта функция возвращает строчный html страницы, но мне нужно получить контент блока `<div class="test"> content </div>` как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://site.com/page2",
  method: "GET"
}).done(function( html ) {
  let content = $(html).find('.test').text();
  console.log(content);
});
```

Comment: Работает, благодарю :)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://site.com/page2', false);
xhr.send();
if (xhr.status != 200) {
  alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText ); // пример вывода: 404: Not Found
} else {
  alert( xhr.responseText.textContent ); // responseText -- текст ответа.
}
```

Comment: Это -- вряд ли.